# Reference to handsontable grid in the onChange event

Tags: handsontable

onChange event does not include a reference to the grid. Almost all of the examples have the grid id hard-coded in the event handlers.
I have a use case with multiple grids on a page. Is there a way to get to the id of the grid from the events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed here: https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/issues/152